# I'm an American journalist in the UK on a tier 2 sponsored visa. If I leave my work, can I go to the Schengen area as a visitor?

Tags: united-kingdom, schengen, freelance

I'm an American in London. After completing a masters degree in the UK, I was offered full-time sponsored employment on a tier 2 visa in London at a trade publication covering commodities. I've worked there for the last two years. But I've determined that my prospects as a journalist are no longer being advanced by trade publication work. I shortly plan to give my one month's notice.

After my tier 2 visa expires, will I be 1) permitted to enter the Schengen area where I could presumably remain for 90 days, and 2) legally allowed to do paid freelance work for media companies or websites?

Thanks.

Comment: For clarity, paid freelance work in the Schengen zone or in the UK? The answer is probably ‘No’ https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/where-can-i-travel-for-prolonged-periods-of-time-while-legally-working-remotely/45492#45492

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, paid freelance journalism in Schengen. I think the key clause in the link you directed me to was -- "V 4.7 The applicant must not receive payment from a UK source for any activities undertaken in the UK, except for the following:" -- which seems to refer only to activities "undertaken in the UK," which of course would not be the case.

Comment: @ScottFreuda indeed, V 4.7 does not apply to work performed in the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly enter the Schengen area for up to 90 days (the actual maximum length depends on how many days you've spent there in the 179 days before entering and on the distribution of those days within that period).  Whether you can work depends on national law, but in general it is forbidden.  There might be exceptions for freelance journalists, but it will depend on which countries you're visiting.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to find out about the relevant national laws.

Comment: @phoog that should be 'last 180 days'

Comment: @MarkJohnson actually, days of presence 91 to 180 days in the past do not reduce the allowable duration of stay.  If someone has spent none of the previous 90 days in the Schengen area, they can enter for 90 days even if their last stay ended 91 days earlier and was 90 days long.

Comment: @phoog from the exit day minus 180, how may days in the Schengen Area is the Formel.

Comment: @MarkJohnson at the end of a 90-day stay, counting back from the date of exit as day 1, the date of entry is day 90, the first day before entry is 91, and the 90th day before entry is 180.  Any days before 180 are irrelevant.  The 90-day period comprising days 91 through 180 is the "last 90 days" before the day of entry.  These are the only days that can reduce the allowable period of stay.

Comment: @MarkJohnson look at it this way.  Assume someone enters on April 1 and leaves on April 2.  If they return later in April, it's clear that 88 days is the maximum length of stay.  If they return in December, it's clear that the maximum is 90 days.  What is the first day when a 90 day stay is possible?  It's July 2, the 91st day after departure.  You can see this for yourself with the [Schengen calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en).

Comment: @phoog my, you do make things complicated. You should ask yourself why it is called **the 90/180 days rule**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98660/discussion-between-phoog-and-mark-johnson).